# Why $\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+x)^\alpha}\sim \frac{2x^2}{x^{\alpha}}$ as $x\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to find for which values of $\alpha$, the integral $\int_{0}^{3}\frac{-2x^2}{(x^2+x)^\alpha}dx$ converges. My textbook says the comparison test for improper integrals is necessary in order to solve it, so for $x\rightarrow 0$, $\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+x)^\alpha}\sim \frac{2x^2}{x^{\alpha}}$. First of all, I can't understand why the two functions are similar for $x\rightarrow 0$, and second how do we know that for $x\rightarrow 0$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=\infty$, which is the condition for the comparison test?

Comment: _First of all, I can't understand why the two functions are similar for_ $x\to0$. Because $x^2 \ll x$ as $x\to0$ and thus $x^2 +x \to x$.

Comment: @denklo Thank you. Also, in order to apply the comparison test, isn't it required that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

$(x^2+x)^\alpha=x^\alpha(x+1)^\alpha∼x^\alpha$ when $x\to 0$; condition for convergence is that $\alpha-2$ is less than 1

Comment: Thanks, but in order to apply the comparison test, isn't it required that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=\infty$?

Comment: Why is it $x^\alpha$, and not $x^{2\alpha}$?

Comment: @Maja: because $x^2<x$ for $0<x<1$...that is, for small enough $x$, we have $x^2\leq\frac x2$.